# Overload []= for deeply nested arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working on a class that uses arrays of arrays nested arbitrarily deep.
I want to overload the `[]` and `[]=` methods so that I can more easily access entries of the nested arrays.
I've got `[]` working, but `[]=` is still giving me problems when I nest more than two levels deep.
Here is the code

```
class Space
  attr_reader :grid

  def initialize(*bounds)
    @dim = bounds.length
    @bounds = bounds
    @grid = create_grid
  end

  def [](*coords)
    entry = @grid
    coords.each { |coord| entry = entry[coord] }
    entry
  end

  def []=(*args)
    row = @grid
    args[0..-3].each { |coord| row = row[coord] }
    row[args[-2]] = args.last
  end

  private

  def create_grid
    sub_grid = nil
    @dim.times do |i|
      sub_grid = Array.new(@bounds[i]) { sub_grid }
    end
    sub_grid
  end
end
```

As you can see, I iteratively create a nested array, nested to a depth of `@dim`.
Then if `space` is an instance of `Space` I want `space[i,j,...] == space[i][j]...` and `space[i,j,...] = x` should be the same as `space[i][j]... = x`
Accessing elements works, but assignment doesn't.
When I run

```
space = Space.new(2,2,2)
space[0,0,0] = true
p space.grid
```

I expect to get

```
[[[true, nil], [nil, nil]], [[nil, nil], [nil, nil]]]
```

but instead I get

```
[[[true, nil], [true, nil]], [[true, nil], [true, nil]]]
```

I suspect the issue is that ruby is only holding one reference to `sub_grid` at each level.
I have partially fixed this by changing `create_grid` to

```
def create_grid
  sub_grid = nil
  @dim.times do |i|
    sub_grid = Array.new(@bounds[i]) do
      sub_grid.nil? ? nil : sub_grid.dup
    end
  end
  sub_grid
end
```

So now my output is

```
[[[true, nil], [nil, nil]], [[true, nil], [nil, nil]]]
```

which is better, but still not quite what I want.
Is there any way to get what I want?

Comment: Seems to me like declaring `Space.new(2,2,2)` is a lot more logical than having to repeat yourself by sending both a number of dimensions, and then the size of each dimension. `args.length` is the number in this revamped example.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the suggestion. I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Since you're creating exponentially more arrays with larger numbers of dimensions or simply larger sizes period you may want to emulate multi-dimensional arrays instead. A 25x25x25 array has 650 separate Array objects, which is kind of wasteful. A singular array of size `25*25*25` is a lot easier on the garbage collector, and you can map your arguments to the appropriate slot in this singular 1D array.

Comment: I see, so I would create a single array of length equal to the product of the bounds, and then simulate a multidimensional array by properly overloading `[]` and `[]=`. This also seems like it would solve my current reference problem.